# API for Commodities Stock markets

Tags: api, data-visualization, finance, scraping, web-apis

I would like to have a clear picture about lithium investments all over the World.

I like [this website](https://www.marketindex.com.au/commodities/lithium) where I can see all companies related to lithium on the Australian Market.

The website also proposes other commodities like nickel, copper, etc...:
[image]

Nice.

But is there any website or API that could provide such information at World scale? I would like to cover US, Latin America, Europe, Asia, etc...

The goal is to create my dashboard through Python, SQL Server and Power BI.

Do you think [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) can provide such service?

Answer (score 1):

I have used marketstack.com for some stock price lookups, not sure whether they also support commodity prices. There is a related Guthub page, see github.com/apilayer/marketstack .

Recently they sent me an email saying that they *"have consolidated all of our over 60 APIs into a single marketplace"* and referring to apilayer.com .